# In React functional components, if I just make a new copy of array but keep the objects, does it break the pattern?

Tags: reactjs, immutability

Let's say if my app or component has an array of `personInfo`.

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([{ name: "", phone: ""}]);
```

so that I can add a person, remove a person, edit the name or phone.

So for the name change, I can have

```
<input onChange={(ev) => handleNameChange(ev.target.value, persons, setPersons, i)} value={e.name} />
```

where `handleNameChange` is

```
const handleNameChange = (newName, persons, setPersons, i) => {
  const newPersons = [...persons];
  newPersons[i].name = newName;
  setPersons(newPerson);
}
```

so it'd work without any problem.  However, one can argue that I am making a new array, but didn't do a deep copy of it, so now I am changing the object inside the array, so it is not **strictly** immutable.

So could it be that some other places, it has a `setTimeout` or something that touches that object (in a previous re-render)?  So it maybe the safest if we make a deep copy of `persons`, but if we just use `[...persons]`, is it, strictly speaking, an anti-pattern, and it'd be better to make it a deep copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is breaking immutability.  You don't necessarily need a deep copy of the whole array, but at least of the object on which you're changing a property and at the level of that changed property.  Normally I'd do something like:

```
const handleNameChange = (newName, persons, setPersons, i) => {
  const newPersons = persons.map((p, j) => (
    j === i ? { ...p, name: newName } : p
  ));
  setPersons(newPersons);
}
```

This would populate `newPersons` with a new array that contains all but one of the original objects, but one of those objects is replaced with a new one that contains all but one of the original properties, but one of those properties is replaced with a new value.

---

As an aside, I'd also recommend not relying on index position for identifying objects.  Instead, give each object a unique identifier (which should also be used as the `key` when rendering the array) and use that identifier to select the object being modified.  For example:

```
const handleNameChange = (newName, persons, setPersons, i) => {
  const newPersons = persons.map(p => (
    p.id === i ? { ...p, name: newName } : p
  ));
  setPersons(newPersons);
}
```

Comment: or how about if we flip the coin, what if it is like in the original question, a new array, but modifying the object, what can go wrong?

Comment: @StefanieGauss: Maybe nothing, maybe something.  Mutating state in React is undefined behavior and makes no guarantees.  In a small example like this, it's entirely likely that it won't cause a problem.  But why get in that habit?  In a more complex component, it could cause bugs including but not limited to: (1) The rendered state doesn't match the actual data, breaking some logic that sits between the state mutation and the next state update; (2) React doesn't observe some update to state and doesn't re-render.

Comment: and I guess you may personally use `useImmer`?